# opening file externally from matlab using command

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do !ce-04.doc which works fine, but file name will not be same since it is user specified, so i had to do the following.

```
fname = 'ce-04.doc'
str = ['!',nameString];
str;
```

Trying this did not work though.

Comment: On Windows, you can also use `winopen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `!command`, you can do `system('command');`, so try:

```
system(nameString)
```

Comment: also, if you do want to run a string as though you had typed it in, you can use `eval(str);`